# Accessing Binary form/data/array of a text file in C

Tags: c, string, binary-data

My understanding is, if we run the function for the binary form of that string, it could be faster.
For example, let, a string "AAABVAVBBA" is written in a text file `test.txt` in the hard drive.

Now I want to run KMP string matching algorithm in C and use the binary string of string "AAABVAVBBA" as input (pattern is already given in binary array).

When we save `test.txt` in the hard drive, it is already in the binary form, so how can I access that binary form of "AAABVAVBBA" in the memory (hard drive) using C?

**Note I am not asking how to convert "AAABVAVBBA" string to a binary string ([like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453505/3989930)). I want to get the binary form already saved in the hard drive (memory)**, which is used by assembler.

My query is close to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45141797/3989930).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but please run and study this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.text", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) return 1;

    char buf[100];
    int r = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
    if(r <= 0) return 1;

    printf("as string: %.*s", r, buf);

    int i;
    printf("as characters:");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) printf(" %c", buf[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("as integers:");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) printf(" %d", buf[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/MiniatureElderlyGoals#main.c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit modified version of @steves program.

https://godbolt.org/z/9dEK6f11h

It writes (and reads of course) in binary and in text mode. Spot the difference if you can. I can't. So you try to solve non-existing problem.

All credit to ***`Steve Summit`*** (upvote his answer)

Comment: You are seeing assembly language, assembler will use this instructions with binary data, if there is a way to see that, you will see, not in the assembly language.

Comment: You are looking into wrong window